# using form is get better than post?

Tags: php

Because when you use post then you click refresh the browser will try to post again.

I watch some tutorial on youtube that show "post then redirect technique".
 he do it like this
after posting redirect(using header) to the same page with some get data in it

if find this stupid because you can use get method instead

So in short my question is this... is get method is better than post method if you use a form??

Comment: http://www.diffen.com/difference/Get_vs_Post

Answer (score 5):

No, it is not better...

*it is worse*

Why? Because pressing refresh would then *repeat whatever action the form performed*. Imagine how many people would accidentally charge their credit cards twice, or submit the same forum posts twice - completely needlessly.

GET requests should be idempotent. Let me make that stronger: GET requests *shall* be idempotent. They should never 'do' anything, but merely request information.

The POST-Redirect-GET method is how you avoid the 'refresh' problem. Period.

Comment: then why <from method="GET"> EXIST??

Comment: I think if you POST-REDIRECT-GET then you use GET to update something on the server.

Comment: @user1628256 Ummm... no. You update with POST, then redirect to an idempotent view that *does nothing*. If your GET changes data, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @user1628256 GET forms exist for *idempotent GET actions*. Like, say, searches. They don't change data - only display it.

Comment: I SEE SO GET TRIES TO MAKE THE SAME ACTION AGAIN? BUT THE BROWSER DIDNT WARN AGAINST IT?

Comment: The browser is not *supposed* to warn about repeated GET requests; it assumes that the web developer followed the W3C standards and did not program the website to 'do' anything on a GET request.

Comment: That actually depends. GET should be used for forms which GET data, POST for forms that POST data (or change the server state). That's about it. That's the difference. It's not about better or worse. It's about different tools for different purposes.

Answer (score 0):

GETs are supposed to have no effect on the server. That is, you should be able to reissue the same GET multiple times and there will be no problem.

In contrast, POSTs are designed to update records. They are not necessarily idempotent. This is why your browser warns you if you try to make the same POST again-- did you really want to buy two copies of that book from Amazon?

If your form is a search form or similar, a GET is appropriate. If your form is a login form, a checkout form, etc... not so much.

Comment: I think if you POST-REDIRECT-GET then you use GET to update something on the server.

Comment: I SEE SO GET TRIES TO MAKE THE SAME ACTION AGAIN? BUT THE BROWSER DIDNT WARN AGAINST IT?

Answer (score 0):

get is not secure.but post so!!! make sure never use get.it's not a better practice.we can use get if the data we are passing is not more useful to user.